# A removed user answered a question. How?

Tags: discussion, deleted-users

This is the post in question: [Remove Everything between Round brackets in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424297/remove-everything-between-round-brackets-in-php#26424428)

A removed user added an answer, and I can't click on the name to view the profile. How was this possible?

Comment: @AmitJoki, -1 not enough [free hand red circles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Aptdz.png) :)

Comment: @gunr2171 "I said NO camels! That's FIVE camels; can't you count?"

Comment: Either the user was removed after answering, or the user was removed before answering.  I don't think the user was removed during answering, but with caching, it might be.  So, of the three choices, which ones are/which one is likely?

Answer (score 19):

The user was removed *after* they posted the answer.

In this case the user deleted their own account

Comment: Did they just post an answer then instantly delete their account? Wonder why...

Comment: @MartinSmith rage from the two downvotes? Unless those were meta-downvotes...

Comment: @canon Is a meta downvote a downvote about downvotes? ;P

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I wish I could downvote your downvote a downvote about downvotes comment.

Comment: @TomHart [Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo)?

Comment: That's my favorite sentence ever.

Comment: Shouldn't be there be a "suggestion for deletion" option on the answer, even if the user have deleted itself?